# Get data value and apply a class if it equals a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

I have a homework assignment that requires the use of gridster.js and I want to be able to check if a list item's data-row attribute equals a certain value and its data-col attribute equals a value. If they do equal the desired value and their coordinates match the intended position I would like to add a class to that list item of "true."

The list item I'm currently trying to achieve this with has an initial `data-row` of `2` and a `data-col` of `1` and I want to check if it has been moved to `data-row` `1` and `data-col` `1`. The code I've tried is this:

```
if ($('.hi').data({row: 1, col: 1})) $('.hi').addClass('true'); }
```

However, this statement results in the class of true being added regardless of position. Ideally what I'm trying to do is check if the `data-row` and `data-col` values for each list item equals the correct values and if they do add the class of true. Then, I am planning on using the `.each` method to check if each list item has a class of `true` and if they do, I would like to change the background color of the div that contains the gridster unordered list.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using `data` as setter which returns a jQuery object and in JavaScript an object is a truthy value, apart from that `data` only returns values of the first matched element in jQuery collection, you can use `filter` method:

```
$('.hi').filter(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   return $this.data('row') === 1 && $this.data('col') === 1;
}).addClass('true');
```

Comment: This has resolved the problem of it adding the class initially but now if the row and col are both at 1 it doesn't apply the class to the list item. Any idea why this might be? P.S. thanks for the info on the data method. I'm still new to Javascript so that explains a lot.

Comment: @TonyBarsotti You are very welcome, can you provide a demo? It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/sdF2Z/

Comment: http://interactivemedia.seancohen.com/fa2012/barsotti_anthony/assignment13/ I'm trying to move the "Hi" block and if it is in the upper right hand corner (row 1, col 1) I want it to then add that class of true to the list item. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @TonyBarsotti I can see in your page that the value of `data-col` attribute is `2`, try with `return $this.data('row') === 1 && $this.data('col') === 2;`.

Comment: Yes but if you drag it to the desired position of row 1 and col 1 (the upper righthand position), those attributes change. I only want the class to be applied if it is in that position.

Comment: @TonyBarsotti Well, then you should listen to the `drag` event, `filter` itself doesn't listen to the events.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29803/discussion-between-tony-barsotti-and-undefined)